# Proving continuity using the definition of being differentiable at $c\in(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ then by the basic definition I have that for any $c\in(a,b)$:

$\lim \limits_{x\to{c}} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c)$ exists and is finite.

Is the following manipulation true?

$\implies \lim \limits_{x\to{c}} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=$ $\frac{\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}[f(x)-f(c)]}{\lim \limits_{x\to{c}} [x-c]}$

$\implies$ $\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}[f(x)-f(c)]=f'(c)$ $\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}$$[x-c]$

$\implies\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}f(x)=f'(c)$ $\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}$$[x-c]+f(c)$

Clearly, $\lim \limits_{x\to{c}}[x-c]=0$ and so we end up with,

$\implies \lim \limits_{x\to{c}}f
(x)=f(c)$

And if I am not mistaken, this is equivalent to $f$ being continuous for all $c\in(a,b)$?

Comment: The first manipulation is false. ${0 \over 0} $ is not defined. Show that the quotient ${f(x) -f(c) \over x-c}$ is bounded for $x$ near $c$.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to c} h(x)/g(x)$ exists and is equal to $(\lim h)/(\lim g)$ if $\lim f$ exists and $\lim g$ exists **and $\lim g$ is nonzero.**

Answer (score 2):

Almost right.... but the algebraic manipulation must be done BEFOR taking limits:

For $x\ne c$, 
$$f(x)-f(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}(x-c).
$$
Now you konw that:

1. $\displaystyle \exists \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c)$.
2. $\displaystyle \exists \lim_{x\to c} (x-c)=0$.

So, there exists the limit of the prodcut of those two functions and is equal to the product of limits, so
$$\exists\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-f(c))=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot \lim_{x\to c} (x-c) =f'(c)\cdot 0=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=f(c)+\underbrace{\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}}_{\underset{x\to  c}{\longrightarrow } f'(c)}\cdot (x-c)\underset{x\to c}{\longrightarrow }f(c).$$